# how to cancel an axios call after some specific time

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm using React, Redux, Axios, and Thunk. In a redux-action the app makes a GET call to receive data but I need to cancel it or asked users to see if they want to cancel it after let's say 10 seconds. I read about Axios cancelation but don't know how to use it with the time manner.

Comment: @CupofJava   could you show me some of the codings and post it as an answer? thanks indeed

Answer (score 1):

Via the documentation from [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation), we can incorporate `setTimeout` that checks the promise status of what we want to cancel

EDIT: It appears there is no standard to check whether a promise has been resolved or not, so you may be able to do something like this:

Where we can check to see if the promise is defined or not

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: source.token
}).catch(function (thrown) {
  if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
    console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
});

const callPromise = axios.post('/user/12345', {
  name: 'new name'
}, {
  cancelToken: source.token
})

// cancel the request by checking the promise
setTimeout(() => {
    if(!callPromise){
        source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
    }
}, 10000)
```

We can also set an external variable that will be set when the promise is resolved

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

let isResolved = false;

axios.post('/user/12345', {
    name: 'new name'
}, {
    cancelToken: source.token
}).then(res => {
    isResolved = true;
})

// cancel the request by checking the promise
setTimeout(() => {
    if(!isResolved){
        source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
    }
}, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//this statement your axious get

    state = {data: [] };
            componentWillMount(){
                axios.get('https://yourwebsite.com')
                .then(Response => this.setState({ data: Response.data}));
            }

//this statement for your setTimeout() function

    setTimeout(() => {
        if(callPromise.isResolved()){
            data.cancel('Canceled');
        }
    }, 15000)
```

Then you need **data.setTimeout()** funtion.

Maybe it will help you!

Comment: that `.setTimeout()` i sthe patr that i don't know where/how to use it. would you please add more info to your answr, thanks